# Media queries no longer update CSS properties if those properties have already been manipulated in JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, media-queries

I'm setting up a responsive layout using floated elements and negative margins.

Resizing my browser everything works nicely: content + left and right sidebars for desktop, content and right sidebar with left sidebar offcanvas for tablet, and both left and right sidebars offcanvas for phone.

I use JavaScript to alter the negative margins to bring, for example, the left sidebar oncanvas when a button is clicked, and to move it back offcanvas when clicked again, back to its original position (confirmed in debugging).

BUT, now that I have manipulated the margins with JavaScript, resizing the browser now breaks the layout because when I pass the media query thresholds, the properties I have updated with JavaScript no longer update.

The media query is still "working" -- the display of the menu button toggles on and off as established in the media queries, for example.

What do I need to do to "refresh" my media queries so they update properties that may have been changed, and then changed back, with JavaScript?

Comment: css added with javascript is added as inline styles and will trump any external style tag or style sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update properties directly on DOM elements, those styles have higher precedence than styles from CSS stylesheets. There's no way to "refresh" things; that's just not how browsers work.

To avoid such problems, update your DOM indirectly by adding/removing classes from elements. You can then control how those classes affect presentation in the stylesheet in ways that are affected by media queries.

Comment: Aha! I should be able to re-jig things to get it working on that basis. Thanks for your help!